# How to reveal all nodes containing a given substring?

Tags: org-mode

Given a simple org-mode outline (i.e. consisting only of heading lines) in its `OVERVIEW` global state (IOW, only the top-level nodes are visible), I want to make *simultaneously* visible all the nodes that mention a given substring.

From the point of view of this aim, Emacs' standard `isearch-forward` (`C-s`) command has two shortcomings:

1. in a given search, only the "current" match is visible; I can reveal subsequent matches by repeatedly hitting `C-s`, but only one<sup>1</sup> matching node is visible at a time.
2. revealing all matches requires hitting `C-s` for each match, which is tedious or impractical when the number of matches is large.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to reveal *all* the matching nodes *at once*, and to do so in a way that minimizes the number of "open" nodes.  (IOW, any node that does not contain additional matching nodes among its *strict* descendants should remain closed.)

How can I achieve this?

---

**Example:**

Consider this artificial example in which the "leaf-level" headings are all 27 length-3 combinations of the characters `a`, `b`, and `c`, and the headings of intermediate nodes represent prefixes of their descendant headings.  (Thus, the leaf node with heading `abc` is a child of the node with heading `ab`, which in turn is a child of the node with heading `a`.)

In the initial (i.e. `OVERVIEW`) state, this outline would look like this:

```
* a...
* b...
* c...
```

Now, if I perform the desired operation (as described above) on this outline, using the substring `ab` as my search term, the outline should look like this:

```
* a
 * aa
  * aaa
  * aab
  * aac
 * ab
  * aba
  * abb
  * abc
 * ac...
* b
 * ba
  * baa
  * bab
  * bac
 * bb...
 * bc...
* c
 * ca
  * caa
  * cab
  * cac
 * cb...
 * cc...
```

Note that the only "open" nodes are those that must be open in order to reveal nodes containing the substring `ab`.

---

EDIT: Following up a suggestion in the comments, below is the result of running `C-c / / ab` on the example's outline:

```
* a
 * aa...
  * aab...
 * ab
  * aba
  * abb
  * abc...
* b
 * ba...
  * bab...
* c
 * ca...
  * cab...
```

This does not really match the description of the desired result, as given in the example, but it is not a bad alternative.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Well, not precisely: in addition to the current matching node, any other matching node that happens to be an ancestor of the current one will be visible as well, but only as a "byproduct" of the current matching node's visibility.</sup>

Comment: Have you tried `C-c /`?

Comment: @Malabarba: as explained in my latest EDIT, `C-c / /` does not produced the desired results, is specified in the original problem statement, but what it does produce is a useful enough alternative that I'd be glad to accept it if you care to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Malabarba Ah nice, I've never used [Sparse trees](http://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-trees.html) before. Much better then my answer, being already part of org-mode. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you're looking for might be
[`org-sparse-tree`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/org-sparse-tree), bound to `C-c /`.
While it doesn't do *exactly* what you asked, it gets pretty close and
is a lot more versatile.

When you hit `C-c /` you'll be prompted with this message:

```
Sparse tree: [/]regexp [t]odo [T]odo-kwd [m]atch [p]roperty
             [d]eadlines [b]efore-date [a]fter-date [D]ates range
             [c]ycle through date types: scheduled/deadline
```

To do a substring search, hit `/` again and type the string. Unlike a
regular search, this will immediately create a sparse tree of the
matches, resulting in something like this:

```
* a
 * aa...
  * aab...
 * ab
  * aba
  * abb
  * abc...
* b
 * ba...
  * bab...
* c
 * ca...
  * cab...
```

As you can see, it *only* shows matches and their parents. This is
different from you what you asked, because it doesn't completely
expand a tree when one of its childs matches (it only shows the
matching child). It may or may not be enough for you.

Answer (score 4):

**Function below will:**

- Prompt user for regexp
- Collapse all headings
- Start searching for regexp from the beginning of the buffer
- Display context around found matches

**Differences from the original request:**

- Content is searched as well, not only headings
- Siblings are not displayed

**Function definition:**

```
(defun org-show-search-term-context ()
  "Show context for the search term"
  (interactive)
  (let ((search-term (read-from-minibuffer "Regexp search: ")))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (org-overview)
    (while (re-search-forward search-term nil t)
      (org-show-context))))
```

**Mapping to `C-c s`:**

```
(eval-after-load 'org
  '(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'org-show-search-term-context))
```

*I'm new to Emacs Lisp so if I something can be improved, let me know.*

Comment: +1!  Even though in the end I picked the answer with the built-in alternative, I found yours very instructive.  Thanks!